# Docker and Angular CLI app

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to use Docker to containerize an app built using the Angular CLI. It's just the default files that come when you use `ng new` so that I can learn how to do this. I'm trying to use a two-step build, where the first step runs `ng-build --prod --build-optimizer`, and then the result of that in the `./dist` folder is put into a container with Nginx that serves the app. I know that if I manually build the app from my command line, then run a Dockerfile with only the second step that I can get the Angular app to be served, but I'd like Docker to do that for me.

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.9-alpine as angular-built
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod --build-optimizer

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="Preston Lamb"
COPY --from=angular-built ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
ENTRYPOINT [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

I've tried using the `node:8.9-alpine` base image as well as the `johnpapa/angular-cli` base image on the first step of the Dockerfile. Everything works until the `RUN ng build --prod --build-optimizer` command, at which point it fails with this error:

> Cannot read property 'config' of null
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of null
>           at Class.run (/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/build.js:15:56)
>           at Class.run (/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/build.js:216:26)
>           at resolve (/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:261:20)
>           at new Promise ()
>           at Class.validateAndRun (/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:240:12)
>           at Promise.resolve.then.then (/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:140:24)
>           at

After googling that, I found that it's because the CLI can't find the `.angular-cli.json` file. Then I read that by default, Linux doesn't copy hidden files, so it doesn't copy the `.angular-cli.json` file, and that's where the error comes up.

My next step was trying to force that file to be copied. I tried both of the following, putting this step right before the `COPY . .` command:

```
COPY .angular-cli.json .angular-cli.json
```

and

```
RUN shopt -s dotglob
```

The first one doesn't seem to do anything; I got the same error as before. The second one produces a different error:

```
/bin/sh: shopt: not found
```

So the command I found to run to tell Linux to copy the hidden files as well doesn't work. I saw one question that was different than this but related say to change the shopt call a little to the following:

```
RUN /bin/sh -c "shopt -s dotglob"
```

But that didn't do anything. I got the same `not found` error.

So I'm not sure where to go from here. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the example Dockerfile in the README of [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/awesome-inc/angular-cli) solves your problem

Comment: Try running `ng init` before the build step.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use a node alpine image to build your angular app, you need to install the angular cli. Notice the `npm i -g @angular/cli` in the `Dockerfile` below. I also added a working directory to the first build stage.

Then you can run the docker compose commands (or docker build and docker run) for an out of the box angular cli app to run on nginx

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:8.9-alpine as angular-built
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN npm i -g @angular/cli
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="John Papa"
COPY --from=angular-built /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

docker-compose.debug.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  clean:
    image: clean
    build: .
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 9229:9229
    ## set your startup file here
    command: [nginx-debug, '-g', 'daemon off;']
```

If you want to use an image based on alpine node 8.9 with the angular cli 1.5.5 already baked in, use this:

Dockerfile

```
FROM johnpapa/angular-cli as angular-built
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
RUN ng build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
LABEL author="John Papa"
COPY --from=angular-built /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

BTW - the 1.5 version of the CLI has the `--build-optimizer` baked in, so it is not needed there

Comment: I created a repo that runs the CLI out of the box that you can try. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-cli-docker-ootb

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly. I used the second Dockerfile example and it worked. I had done everything except setting the `WORKDIR`, so next time I'll remember that as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JohnPapa i followed the same steps but when i run docker-compose up the nginx gets started but exits when i break the shell. When i move to production i will have to run it in backgroun right? Any idea why. Thanks